# Place dependency files in subdirectory when creating makefiles

Tags: c, makefile, dependencies, subdirectory

I am trying to create dependency files and place them into a subdirectory named deps (already created). After reading the man page for gcc I thought that -MF was the way to go but when trying the code below a dependency file wasn´t created and no error messages were shown.

```
DDIR=deps

$(DDIR)/%.d: %.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -MF"$@" -MG -MM -MP -MT"$@" -MT"$(<:.c=.o)" "$<"´
```

Is it possible to specify where to put a dependency file or do you have to place it in the same folder as the makefile?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can put the prerequisite file where you want.  Your rule specifies how to build $(DDIR)/%.d.  Is that really the thing you're trying to build?  Do you see this command line printed by make, with these options in it?  If you run that same command line from the shell, does it do what you want?

Does the directory `ddir` exist?

With the information you've provided my suspicion is that make is not using your rule and is instead using a built-in rule, that doesn't have the various `-M` options you've provided.

It's best if you show the make command you typed, and show the output that make printed, when asking questions about behavior.

Comment: by looking at the make command I could see that I typed wrong, I changed it a bit and got it to work, thank you for your answer and I'll give more info to my question next time!